# How Do I support JSON with circular references using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, dojo

In brief, I'm looking for a way move complex object graphs between browser code (jQuery) and server code (ASP.NET MVC). JSON does not support object references, so standard serialization of a circular referencing object is not possible out-of-the-box.

A proposed standard for JSON object references is floating about, which is currently implemented by DoJox, and (apparently) by .NET's DataContractJsonSerializer class.

While DoJo appears to be a mature JavaScript library, I'm loath to run DoJo side-by-side with jQuery.

Does any one know of a technique or plugin that will allow me to serialize, deserialize complex JSON object graphs with jQuery?

Comment: this question contains the answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782052/using-javascript-to-deserialize-references-in-a-complex-object-graph-from-signal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it doesn't allow you to serialize circular references, in .NET there is the [ScriptIgnore] attribute you can place on your ViewModels, which will prevent properties from being serialized for JSON and thus avoid the circular reference error so common with complex relations in MVC.

Also, instead of returning your model as-is, using LINQ or anonymous objects to return only the properties you *need* to represent in your client side script will help you out with performance by minimizing the amount of data being sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.NET supports circular references through preserving all references.  It very straightforwardly adds a "$id" field to each object in the JSON string, and encodes object references as `{"$ref"=1}` where the number 1 would correspond to some object's "$id" value.

So although this has been solved on the server-side, I'm still wondering how to take advantage of it on the client-side.  I asked this question ([Is there a JavaScript (client-side) JSON library that integrates well with JSON.NET (server-side) and supports the "preserve references" feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18065857/88409)) to see if anyone knows of any libraries that support it.

If not, you'd have to write it yourself.  It would be a fairly straightforward two-pass process.  First, deserialize the entire string, and as you create each object add it to a hash table using its "$id" value as the key.  When you encounter references (object consisting of just a "$ref" property) you could add it to a list of object+fieldname that you could go back over to replace the reference with the final object once all objects have been constructed.