# Using JavaScript to deserialize references in a complex object graph from SignalR/Json.NET

Tags: javascript, json, json.net, deserialization, signalr

I'm using SignalR to return a complex object graph to my JavaScript client. This object graph has multiple references throughout to the same object, so the JSON that SignalR/Json.NET returns looks a lot like this:

```
{
    "$id": "57",
    "Name": "_default",
    "User": {
        "$id": "58",
        "UserTag": "ken",
        "Sessions": [{
            "$id": "59",
            "SessionId": "0ca7474e-273c-4eb2-a0c1-1eba2f1a711c",
            "User": {
                "$ref": "58"
            },
            "Room": {
                "$ref": "57"
            }
        }],
    },

    "Sessions": [{
        "$ref": "59"
    }]
}
```

(Of course, a lot more complicated in real life, but you get the idea.)

And of course, when Json.NET is serializing by reference rather than by value, it assigns each object a $id value (e.g., `"$id":"57"`, and then later just refers to that object using that id (e.g., `"$ref":"57"`. And so far as I can tell, when it is Json.NET (using C#/.NET) that is deserializing those references, it places the appropriate instances of the object in the appropriate places.

All good so far - but what's the best way to deserialize these *in JavaScript*, so that I actually get the appropriate object instances in the appropriate places, instead of just weird $ref fields?

I could presumably write my own general-purpose deserializer, but I have to imagine that somebody else has already tackled this problem, and I'd just as soon not reinvent any wheels. Unfortunately, my Google skills apparently aren't sufficient to locate that solution :-).

Edit:

I see that there's an [IETF draft proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03) about how this sort of thing is supposed to work. And it looks like the always helpful Douglas Crockford has a [tentative implementation](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) of it. Unfortunately, the IETF proposal uses a different schema than Json.NET uses.

Comment: I am curious how would you de-serialize the object in your example, where it refers to itself ($id=57)?

Comment: That's part of the magic of a good deserializer :-). But yeah, it's figuring out those bits that I'd rather not do myself if somebody else has done all the hard work.

Comment: my point is that if a deserializer replaces the references with actual objects then in your example you will get an object of infinite depth.

Comment: It's only infinite if you insist on traversing it :-). In memory, it's just pointer A pointing at pointer B, which in turn points back to pointer A. If you're working with something like Microsoft's Entity Framework, you get stuff like that all the time, and it's not a problem. You just need to have a deserializer that knows how to deal with it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, I think this will do it. I modified Crockford's [cycle.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js) to handle the reference format that Json.NET uses. And because TypeScript is an unspeakably better language than JavaScript, I rewrote it in TS. I certainly don't swear that it has no bugs (if anybody points them out, I'll try to fix 'em), but it seems to handle the complex object graphs I've throw at it so far.

```
export function retrocycle(obj: any): void {
    var catalog: any[] = [];
    catalogObject(obj, catalog);
    resolveReferences(obj, catalog);
}

function catalogObject(obj, catalog: any[]):void {

    // The catalogObject function walks recursively through an object graph
    // looking for $id properties. When it finds an object with that property, then
    // it adds it to the catalog under that key.

    var i: number;
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        var id:string = obj.$id;
        if (typeof id === 'string') {
            catalog[id] = obj;
        }

        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
                catalogObject(obj[i], catalog);
            }
        } else {
            for (name in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {
                    catalogObject(obj[name], catalog);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveReferences(obj: any, catalog: any[]) {

    // The resolveReferences function walks recursively through the object looking for $ref
    // properties. When it finds one that has a value that is an id, then it
    // replaces the $ref object with a reference to the object that is found in the catalog under
    // that id.

    var i:number, item:any, name:string, id:string;

    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
                item = obj[i];
                if (item && typeof item === 'object') {
                    id = item.$ref;
                    if (typeof id === 'string') {
                        obj[i] = catalog[id];
                    } else {
                        resolveReferences(item, catalog);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (name in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {
                    item = obj[name];
                    if (item) {
                        id = item.$ref;
                        if (typeof id === 'string') {
                            obj[name] = catalog[id];
                        } else {
                            resolveReferences(item, catalog);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the equivalent JS:

```
function retrocycle(obj) {
    var catalog = [];
    catalogObject(obj, catalog);
    resolveReferences(obj, catalog);
}

function catalogObject(obj, catalog) {
    var i;
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        var id = obj.$id;
        if (typeof id === 'string') {
            catalog[id] = obj;
        }
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
                catalogObject(obj[i], catalog);
            }
        } else {
            for (name in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {
                    catalogObject(obj[name], catalog);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function resolveReferences(obj, catalog) {
    var i, item, name, id;
    if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.apply(obj) === '[object Array]') {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
                item = obj[i];
                if (item && typeof item === 'object') {
                    id = item.$ref;
                    if (typeof id === 'string') {
                        obj[i] = catalog[id];
                    } else {
                        resolveReferences(item, catalog);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (name in obj) {
                if (typeof obj[name] === 'object') {
                    item = obj[name];
                    if (item) {
                        id = item.$ref;
                        if (typeof id === 'string') {
                            obj[name] = catalog[id];
                        } else {
                            resolveReferences(item, catalog);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You use it kinda like so (assuming you've got SignalR hubs wired up):

```
$.connection.roomHub.server.joinRoom()
    .done(function(room) {
        retrocycle(room);
    });
```

I also created a quick-and-dirty little repository out on BitBucket for it: https://bitbucket.org/smithkl42/jsonnetdecycle.

Comment: Just to make sure - for anyone finding this, use the code out on the BitBucket repo (https://bitbucket.org/smithkl42/jsonnetdecycle), rather than the code here. I've been maintaining and fixing bugs in that code, including a couple important ones having to do with correct handling of arrays.

Comment: @KenSmith, please insert your comment into your answers as a lot of people do not read comment unfortunately

Comment: I've been trying to use JsonNetDecycle, but it seems to be substituting the wrong Id for a particular object. The data going in to decycle is correct, but the data coming out replaces a User object with a $ref to a Country. Most everything else in the graph seems okay, but I see two cases where the reference Ids point to entirely the wrong objects. I'm not sure where to even start on this one.